# ASP.net MVC - how does controller action method gets parameter value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

I know the title of this question isn't very pretty. I dint have a better way to put it.

Lets look at the following code :

**View for delete action:**

```
@model LearningMVC.Models.Blog

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Blog</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.URL)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.URL)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

**Controller action  for delete action**

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Blog blog = db.Blogs.Find(id);
            db.Blogs.Remove(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

### My questions is, How on earth this method got its parameter ?!

Comment: Whats the parameter ? Correct ID ? or maybe some default value ?

Comment: The answer is, it can't.  At least not from the code you've shown.  Perhaps there is some javascript that is modifying the form's parameters?